Touched to tears
Is "touch one to tears" correct usage?
For example:

The veteran's story of his time in the war was so moving that I was touched to tears.


It's not incorrect to say "touched to tears", but it is so uncommon that it immediately calls attention to itself.
moved to tears is so much more common than any other "____ to tears" phrase that anything else looks strange.
